# Conditional Approvers

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm making a SPD 2013 custom workflow for a document set. I want to assign a task assignment and if a certain column equals a value also assign it to another user. Is this possible? Or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You can do this through SharePoint Designer 2013. You can create a workflow for a document library. You can additional clauses where you can look at one or multiple columns, and pass conditions whereby they must equal certain values. It would essentially be if else statements.

Check the below screenshot.

[image]

UPDATE: Screenshot with two conditions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I'm looking to do something like this.'If column equals this value - email these users, if another column also equals this value - email this user as well', is that possible?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Here, check the screenshots above (I've updated them).

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. So do you know if it's possible to add users inside of a 'start approval process'? For instance, when initiating the process, you have to add users, but is it possible to add add conditional users to the process?